# Integrating WP7 app to the system

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How to integrate an app so that it can be shown in some of the system's options, like photo enhancer app with the Pictures app, or the Channel9/HTC YouTube/TouchDevelop with the music&Videos app?

Do I have to get approval from somewhere to make this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [How to: Integrate with the Music and Videos Hub for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769558%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)? If I understand your question, it is exactly what you're looking for. If not, can you please clarify what you're trying to achieve? Best wishes!